# top command with options -bn doesn't match results without options

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to record the information of a process from `top` to a file periodically. I tried executing `top -bn1 | grep [process_name] >> /tmp/some_file` every once in a while, but this command always returns the same CPU and memory usage value, and doesn't match the values that I observe from executing `top` command alone. However, if I change `-n 1` to `-n 2` or a larger number, the results do eventually match.
For example, the result from `top -bn1 | grep [process_name] >> /tmp/some_file` after executing many times:

```
1138 root   ... 0.0  0.2   1:03.72 app
1138 root   ... 0.0  0.2   1:04.27 app
1138 root   ... 0.0  0.2   1:04.31 app
1138 root   ... 0.0  0.2   1:04.33 app
1138 root   ... 0.0  0.2   1:04.35 app
```

At the same time, if I do `top | grep app`, the results are:

```
// dynamically changing results
1138 root   ... 0.7  0.2   1:04.35 app
1138 root   ... 0.2  0.2   1:04.35 app
1138 root   ... 0.3  0.2   1:04.35 app
1138 root   ... 0.1  0.2   1:04.35 app
1138 root   ... 0.2  0.2   1:04.35 app
```

And `top -b -n 2|grep app >> /tmp/some_file` gives something like:

```
1138 root   ... 0.0  0.2   1:04.35 app
1138 root   ... 0.7  0.2   1:04.35 app
1138 root   ... 0.0  0.2   1:04.35 app
1138 root   ... 0.2  0.2   1:04.35 app
...
```

The process name "app" is unique. There's no other process with this name running.
Is there any reason why behind this? To accurately record the information of the process, should I use the result from `top` alone without any options? If so, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Have tried somethin like `top -p \`pgrep "app"\``

Comment: @Ôrel it does give better results, thank you. Would you happen to know if there's any way I can print just the last line of output `1138 root   ... 0.0  0.2   1:04.35 app` without the headings to the text file? I tried `top -p $(pgrep "app" )| grep "app" >> /tmp/file` but this doesn't print anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `-b` as you work on batch mode

`-n1` as you want only one value

Then you want the last line: `tail -1`

And finally happen to a file `>> /tmp/file`

```
top -b -n1 -p 4340 |tail -1 >> /tmp/file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can omit `-n` to get a continuous stream of data.

Following script (`./test.sh`) is an example that you can adapt to suit your needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

top -b -p $$ | while read line; do
    [[ $line = *bash ]] && echo $line
done
```